# c3p0 acronym origin - jdbc connection pool name

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0, acronym

Can anyone share the origin and meaning of the jdbc connection pool named c3p0.

Was it inspired from star wars?.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Quoting Steve Waldman (C3P0 Developer) in the [Hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2240525#p2240525):

> re: why c3p0? mostly because it began as an attempt to see how hard it would be to implement connection pooling as defined by the JDBC 3.0 specification. Connection Pooling 3.0 --> cp30 --> c3p0. Also, I was working on a (never completed, and now obseleted) project for easy-to-use access to berkeley db from java, and that was called bdbd. A robot in an old television show (Buck Rogers) always said "bdbd", and c3p0 was a robot too. The pairing of names was a private little joke.